# Using php and doveadm to create password

Tags: php, email, hash, dovecot

I've created an registration page in php with an mysql backend.
If the user is entering his new password it should become SHA512-CRYPT via doveadm.

This is what I have now,

```
$password=hash('sha256', $pass);
```

But I want to create a password hash with doveadm because of my mail server:

```
$password=(/usr/bin/doveadm pw -s SHA512-CRYPT -p "$pass")
```

But it doesn't seem to work, how can i implement this "doveadm" command in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call it with [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) method:

```
$password = shell_exec('/usr/bin/doveadm pw -s SHA512-CRYPT -p '. $pass);
```

Comment: but be aware: make sure your password is sane before passing it to shell_exec. or i can guarantee at some point, some user signs up with a password among the lines of `; rm -rf /`

Answer (score 1):

Avoid to use shell_exec is dangerous, if you use the default config of dovecot as the command on your example then the dovecot produces a hash with a 16 chars (bytes) salt, as a  result you can use the php function crypt to produce the same result and you will avoid the use of shell_exec

see below example

```
echo crypt("1234567890",'$6$Wh4t3v3rS4ltH3re'); //$6$ This part declares the SHA 512 and after the second $ must be 16 chars salt
```

will give you compatible result with the doveadm pw command